# Oracle Trigger to rebuild an Index

Tags: oracle, triggers

How can I create a trigger in Oracle to rebuild an index?

```
create or replace  
 TRIGGER BI_NAME_SEARCH AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PROFILE
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
   ALTER INDEX MYINDEX REBUILD;  
END;
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want to do this, ever:

- You would need to put a trigger on a system table, which you really don't want to do, ever.
- You would then need to perform DDL dynamically in a trigger, which you really don't want to do, ever.

If you need to rebuild an index this should be done as part of standard system maintenance, not on the fly. If you have a need to rebuild indexes on the fly then you are doing something which is making the index unusable. Don't do whatever this is. Fix the root cause of the issue rather than the symptoms.

To actually answer your question (once again don't do this) you need to use dynamic DDL in order to perform DDL in PL/SQL. Use [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317)

```
execute immediate 'alter index myindex rebuild';
```

Comment: Why would you need an trigger on a system table? It seems to be trying to rebuild the index whenever data changes in the `profile` table, which perhaps suggests a fundamental misunderstanding of how indexes are maintained; but I'm missing the system reference?

Comment: To do it properly you'd only want to rebuild the index if it became unusable @Alex, hence you'd have to use `***$` (hidden on purpose!). I hadn't considered the option you've suggested though... it could be that.

Comment: Ah, OK, I wasn't thinking about detecting it was unusable. Yes, a trigger on that would not be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. Trigger created successfully by using `execute immediate`

Comment: As I say you should really reconsider whether this is necessary @user. I would ask another question about whether there's a better way, including details of the reason why you need to do this.

Comment: Please note that PROFILE is not a system table.I am using Oracle Text for searching.So that I have created CONTEXT index and implemented searching. But Oracle Text search is not working for the data which inserted or updated after the index creation.So I wanted to rebuild the index to enable search for updated data.

Comment: You don't need to rebuild the index to do that @user. There's a function [`CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cddlpkg.htm#i998469) to do it for you (assuming I've got the right type of text index - double check). There are suggestions for optimisation in the docs so I'd read the entire thing. Rebuilding the index will lock the index, which you don't want to do online.

Comment: ORA-14086: a partitioned index may not be rebuilt as a whole